# Why does null check fail even though object is explicitly initialized as null

Tags: c#, inheritance, null, abstract-class, null-check

I have created a custom **abstract** class, which in turn of course derived classes were also created.

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseClass
...

public class ChildClass1 : AbstractBaseClass
...
```

Now, whenever I declare for example **`AbstractBaseClass baseClass = null`**, and wherever null checks follow after this initialization, it always fails.

```
if (baseClass == null)
{
    // this block is never reached - condition always evaluates to false
    // let's say AbstractBaseClass baseClass = null is at line 10
    // even if this condition is at line 11, condition still fails
}
```

Reason why there is a null check is because there are multiple derived classes, and on some process, I determine which type would it be (e.g. using switch cases). And of course there are invalid cases, in which I expect that the value would be the initialized **null**.

This is really weird, and I really am expecting that null check would evaluate to true.

What could be the possible causes why this happens (*so that I can add more sample code depending on the info as the whole relevant code is quite big*), and how should one fix this? Thank you.

**EDIT**:

Also, debugger value is null.

Oh that's right, as @taffer mentioned, == is overloaded for `AbstractBaseClass`. Here is that part and other relevant code:

```
    protected bool Equals(AbstractBaseClass other)
    {
        return Equals(this.SomeUniqueProperty, other.SomeUniqueProperty);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return obj.GetType() == this.GetType() && this.Equals((AbstractBaseClass)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (this.SomeUniqueProperty != null ? this.SomeUniqueProperty.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(AbstractBaseClass a, AbstractBaseClass b)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, a))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return !ReferenceEquals(null, b) && a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(AbstractBaseClass a, AbstractBaseClass b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }
```

Comment: when using the debugger and setting a breakpoint what value actually is in `baseclass`?

Comment: show us https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: When I watch the value, it is null, that's why I'm really confused :(

Comment: Did you re-compile your project?

Comment: Show a reproducible example. It can be anything. Is == operator overloaded, for example?

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes I rebuild the solution many times already. And also, this null check is performed in many places, and currently would break the application logic.

Comment: @MichaelRandall I tried to reproduce with just the bare bones code, but null check succeeds :( https://dotnetfiddle.net/ShbVT1

Comment: Is it because you can't instantiate an abstract class, what happens if you do the check for if(baseClass == default(BaseClass))

Comment: @taffer yes I forgot about that, I edited the post now to reflect the additional code.

Comment: @MichaelRandall  now I was able to reproduce the actual result with the updated code. https://dotnetfiddle.net/rXrojC

Comment: Why would you overload the ``==`` operator in such an unintuitive way? Abstractions like operator overloading can be used to make code concise and elegant but this is clearly an example of how to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: This piece of code is quite old now. As I remember, this maybe a combination of Resharper generated code and copy+paste. Makes sense now.

Comment: @RufusL this would definitely produce stackoverflowexception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `==` overload is wrong, as you are returning false if `a` is null, ignoring the fact that `b` could also be `null`.

What you need to do is return true if both are `null`, or if `a` equals `b`:

```
public static bool operator ==(AbstractBaseClass a, AbstractBaseClass b)
{
    var isANull = ReferenceEquals(null, a);
    var isBNull = ReferenceEquals(null, b)
    return (isANull && isBNull) || a?.Equals(b) ?? false;
}
```

Note: In case `a` is null but `b` is not, the `.?` operator will return null, and the `??` operator will return `false`.

As RufusL wrote in the comments, there's a shorter eqiuvalent code to get the same results:

```
public static bool operator ==(AbstractBaseClass a, AbstractBaseClass b)
{
    return a?.Equals(b) ?? ReferenceEquals(null, b);
}
```

if `a` is null, return true if `b` is also null. if `a` is not null, return the result of `a.Equals(b)`.

In case `a` is not null but `b` is, your `Equals` method should return false:

```
protected bool Equals(AbstractBaseClass other)
{
    return other != null 
        ? Equals(this.SomeUniqueProperty, other.SomeUniqueProperty) 
        : false;
}
```